# "portlet is temporarily unavailable" shows when edit page with validation refreshes

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

1. Loads `view.jsp` page.
2. click edit button.
3. It opens edit page
4. submit page
5. validation shows
6. Refreshes page.
7. It shows `portlet is temporary unavailable`

Please tell me how can we solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at step 6: What do you cause on the portal? E.g. do you send a "render" request or the same "action" request that you sent in step 4?

Most likely whatever you're processing in the background throws an exception that you don't catch - thus Liferay can't know how/what to display. Assuming you're using GenericPortlet, take a look at your processAction or doView, guard it with a try/catch block and identify what exception is thrown where. (if you use any UI framework on top of the portlet API, use the equivalent wrapper to these API methods). You might find an exception in the log already.

If your reload triggers processAction again, you might want to send a redirect at the end of your action, so that an action is only ever triggered once (HTTP standard safeguard)